# T-SQL Recursive Division

Tags: sql, sql-server, division

How do I perform recursive division in SQL?

I know the basic premise is

```
declare @i = 0
declare @testValue bigint = FLOOR(@num/@dem)
while @testValue>0
begin
   set @num = @num - @testValue*@dem
   set @testValue = FLOOR(@num/@dem)
   set @i = @i + 1
end
```

, but I do not know how to do this in an efficient manner.

Comment: What is `@num`?  What is `@dem`? What is `@i` even being used for? What are you trying to do with this query..?

Comment: `@num` = numerator, `@dem` = denominator, `@i` = the loop iteration

Comment: Curious... what's the use case?

Comment: FYI, this is not recursive division, it is repeated division. It is only recursive if there is a function and that function calls itself.

Comment: Eli, I'm trying to create a GUID (using Base62 -- i.e. 0-9A-Z) from an integer value.

Comment: Doesn't work like that @wk4997 for SQL. Do you have a table that you want to divide? You use the values in the table using ID's.  Here's a sample recursion that I posted that goes through a database that splits the values between two pipe delimiters. This is probably the closest I can think of at the moment.           https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44530932/how-to-parse-hl7-delimiters-using-only-ms-sql-syntax

Comment: I tried a CTE and got this far...

`--copy original number
`declare @workingNum bigint = @numerator
`--set denominator
`declare @denominator int = 36
`
`
`; with DivisionCTE AS (
` select [Iteration] = cast(0 as int)
`     , [Value] = cast(@numerator as bigint)
`     , [Rem] = cast(0 as int)
` UNION ALL
` select [Iteration]+1, [Value] = [Value]/@denominator, [Rem] = `cast([Value]%@denominator as int)
` from DivisionCTE
` where [Value]>0
`)
`select * from DivisionCTE
`where Iteration>0

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0):

Your query can be rewritten as the following:

```
Declare @Num BigInt = 10000,
        @Dem BigInt = 50

;With Cte As
(
    Select  Floor(@num / @dem) TestValue, 1 As Iteration
    Union All
    Select  Floor((TestValue * @Dem) / @Dem) As TestValue, Iteration + 1
    From    Cte
    Where   TestValue > 0
)
Select  *
From    Cte
```

But there's a problem with the design of it.  It multiplies the value back to the division result, and divides again, resulting in an infinite loop.

I *believe* this is what you were trying to do:

```
Declare @Num BigInt = 10000,
        @Dem BigInt = 50

;With Cte As
(
    Select  Floor(@num / @dem) TestValue, 1 As Iteration
    Union All
    Select  Floor(TestValue / @Dem) As TestValue, Iteration + 1
    From    Cte
    Where   TestValue > 0
)
Select  *
From    Cte
```

Which, in this case gives the following results:

```
TestValue   Iteration
200         1
4           2
0           3
```